# Book on History of Plant Names and their category and variety

Tags: resource-request, academic-latin, book

In Pliny's History of Nature, the author writes about different kind of trees and their varieties, but as per this [book](https://web.archive.org/web/20161229101439/http://www.masseiana.org/pliny.htm#THE%20BOTANY%20OF%20PLINY:%7E:text=an%20unmixed%20blessing.-,THE%20BOTANY%20OF%20PLINY,-The%20identification%20of) "when certain that a Latin or Greek name is generally equivalent to an English one, the botanist is not sure that a variety included by Pliny, or Theophrastus, under the former should also be included under the latter", I want more information about this, But I don't know which kind of books should I read to get this information